# Java stream remove first three elements

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

I have list of object sorted by student `id`:

```
List<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
arraylist.add(new Student(1, "Chaitanya", 26));
arraylist.add(new Student(2, "Chaitanya", 26));
arraylist.add(new Student(3, "Rahul", 24));
arraylist.add(new Student(4, "Ajeet", 32));
arraylist.add(new Student(5, "Chaitanya", 26));
arraylist.add(new Student(6, "Chaitanya", 26));
```

I would like to use **stream** and remove only first three elements where student `age` equals `26`.
Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `skip` as :

```
List<Student> finalList = arraylist.stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getAge() == 26) // filters the students with age 26
        .skip(3) // skips the first 3 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will result in listing `Student`s with age equal to 26 while at the same time skipping first three occurrences of such students.

---

On the other hand, if you just want to exclude those three students from the complete list, you can also do it as:

```
List<Student> allStudentsExcludingFirstThreeOfAge26 = Stream.concat(
            arraylist.stream().filter(a -> a.getAge() != 26),
            arraylist.stream().filter(a -> a.getAge() == 26).skip(3))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Do note, that this could result in changing the original order of the list.

Comment: @Artifex Have updated the answer for that use case as well.

Comment: Good solution, however, be aware that it changes the order of elements in the list.

Comment: @Andreas Hmm, interesting, was thinking over the streams behavior itself. True and updated that as a note. Apart from that, wondering if I could just have used a `Predicate.not` kind of implementation and not created streams twice as in my code. Aware of any such constructs?

Comment: Since the request is about "first three", i.e. an ordered test, it precludes implementation supporting parallel streams anyway, which means you can violate the rules and write a stateful filter.

Comment: @ernest_k thanks, I initially thought of the problem to be what I suggested a solution for. Updated later.

Answer (score 6):

first search for the elements you wish to remove via the stream API:

```
List<Student> toRemove = arraylist.stream()
                                  .filter(x -> x.getAge() == 26)
                                  .limit(3)
                                  .collect(toList());
```

then remove from the source list:

```
toRemove.forEach(arraylist::remove);
```

if you don't want to mutate the source then clone it first:

```
List<Student> resultSet = new ArrayList<>(arraylist);
List<Student> toRemove = arraylist.stream().filter(x -> x.getAge() == 26).limit(3)
                                  .collect(toList());
toRemove.forEach(resultSet::remove);
```

After all, this may be better implemented using an iterator:

```
int counter = 0;
for (Iterator<Student> it = arraylist.iterator(); it.hasNext();){        
      if(counter == 3) break;
      Student student = it.next();
      if (student.getAge() == 26){
          it.remove();
          counter++;
      }
}
```

Comment: Although [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) only removes the first match, [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) will remove *all* matches. `removeAll()` is not equivalent to calling `remove()` for each element of the passed-in collection.

Comment: @Andreas right I see, iterator approach solves that i believe.

Comment: Of course, the iterator approach doesn't use streams as requested by the question.

Comment: @Andreas sure, thing, sometimes the best approach is not via streams.

Comment: Totally agree. Streams is a very handy tool, but not the tool for every job. A good programmer will know which tool is best for a job, and not insist on using a hammer to chop wood, instead of using an axe.

Comment: It might be reasonable not to expect multiple occurrences of the same student in a list, so `removeAll` might still be the way to go. Otherwise, `arraylist.removeIf(toRemove::remove);` might be more efficient when the list is large and the elements to remove are at the beginning of the list.